# BigQuery: How to run cohort / retention analysis for userbase across 2.5 years?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have been asked to complete a cohort/retention analysis for an assignment for over 50K users for an app, based on purchases, across 2.5 years.

I have two tables I can reference. One table showing user_id and date of account signup (in TIMESTAMP format). The other table shows purchase made by users on the app, with each purchase having TIMESTAMP associated with it.

How exactly would I write a query to conduct such an analysis? I have looked at some examples on StackOverflow, Reddit and other forums and many of those examples are for only one month or several weeks of user signups as opposed to several years where new users signed up every month across the two years.

## Table 1

-timestamp  TIMESTAMP

-user_id    BYTES

## Table 2

-user_id    BYTES

-account_signup     TIMESTAMP

Comment: Its unclear what exact results you are after. Show the query. Exactly how big are these because the one month solution is equally applicable and equally as fast where is the 30 times less data. There doesn't seem to be a time limit requirement on the query so use the same pattern. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 2):

— extracting relevant columns —

```
 With step_1 as (
    Select
    customer_email as user_id,
    date(created_at) as order_date,
    FROM `ordertable` order by 1,2 asc
    ),
```

— Getting date of acquisition —

```
step_2 as(
Select
user_id,
order_date,
CASE user_id
WHEN LAG(user_id) OVER (order by 1,2 asc) THEN First_value(order_date) OVER (partition by user_id order by 1,2 asc)
ELSE order_date
END
as acquisition_date
from step_1
),
```

— Defining cohorts and days between order date & acquisition date —

```
step_3 as (
Select
user_id,
order_date,
acquisition_date,
date_diff(order_date,acquisition_date,DAY) as repeat_after_days,
concat(cast(format_date(“%E4Y”, cast(acquisition_date as date)) as string),’-’,cast(format_date(“%m”, cast(acquisition_date as date)) as string)) as cohort
from step_2
),
```

— Absolute Order number cohort table (we can stop here for getting the number of repeat orders per cohort) —

```
repeat_cohort_numbers as (
select
cohort,
count(distinct user_id) as users,
countif(repeat_after_days <= 30)-count(distinct user_id) as repeat_m0,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 60 AND repeat_after_days > 30) as repeat_m1,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 90 AND repeat_after_days > 60) as repeat_m2,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 120 AND repeat_after_days > 90) as repeat_m3,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 150 AND repeat_after_days > 120) as repeat_m4,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 180 AND repeat_after_days > 150) as repeat_m5,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 210 AND repeat_after_days > 180) as repeat_m6,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 240 AND repeat_after_days > 210) as repeat_m7,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 270 AND repeat_after_days > 240) as repeat_m8,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 300 AND repeat_after_days > 270) as repeat_m9,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 330 AND repeat_after_days > 300) as repeat_m10,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 360 AND repeat_after_days > 330) as repeat_m11,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 390 AND repeat_after_days > 360) as repeat_m12,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 420 AND repeat_after_days > 390) as repeat_m13,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 450 AND repeat_after_days > 420) as repeat_m14,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 480 AND repeat_after_days > 450) as repeat_m15,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 510 AND repeat_after_days > 480) as repeat_m16,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 540 AND repeat_after_days > 510) as repeat_m17,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 570 AND repeat_after_days > 540) as repeat_m18,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 600 AND repeat_after_days > 570) as repeat_m19,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 630 AND repeat_after_days > 600) as repeat_m20,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 660 AND repeat_after_days > 630) as repeat_m21,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 690 AND repeat_after_days > 660) as repeat_m22,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 720 AND repeat_after_days > 690) as repeat_m23,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 750 AND repeat_after_days > 720) as repeat_m24,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 780 AND repeat_after_days > 750) as repeat_m25,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 810 AND repeat_after_days > 780) as repeat_m26,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 840 AND repeat_after_days > 810) as repeat_m27,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 870 AND repeat_after_days > 840) as repeat_m28,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 900 AND repeat_after_days > 870) as repeat_m29,
countif(repeat_after_days<= 930 AND repeat_after_days > 900) as repeat_m30
from step_3
group by cohort order by cohort asc
)
/*
— Cohort behaviour (by percentage) table —
select
cohort,
users,
repeat_m0/users as m0_order_percent,
repeat_m1/users as m1_order_percent,
repeat_m2/users as m2_order_percent,
repeat_m3/users as m3_order_percent,
repeat_m4/users as m4_order_percent,
repeat_m5/users as m5_order_percent,
repeat_m6/users as m6_order_percent,
repeat_m7/users as m7_order_percent,
repeat_m8/users as m8_order_percent,
repeat_m9/users as m9_order_percent,
repeat_m10/users as m10_order_percent,
repeat_m11/users as m11_order_percent,
repeat_m12/users as m12_order_percent,
repeat_m13/users as m13_order_percent,
repeat_m14/users as m14_order_percent,
repeat_m15/users as m15_order_percent,
repeat_m16/users as m16_order_percent,
repeat_m17/users as m17_order_percent,
repeat_m18/users as m18_order_percent,
repeat_m19/users as m19_order_percent,
repeat_m20/users as m20_order_percent,
repeat_m21/users as m21_order_percent,
repeat_m22/users as m22_order_percent,
repeat_m23/users as m23_order_percent,
repeat_m24/users as m24_order_percent,
repeat_m25/users as m25_order_percent,
repeat_m26/users as m26_order_percent,
repeat_m27/users as m27_order_percent,
repeat_m28/users as m28_order_percent,
repeat_m29/users as m29_order_percent,
repeat_m30/users as m30_order_percent
from repeat_cohort_numbers
*/
```

— Final cohort summary table —

```
select
sum(users) as net_users,
sum(repeat_m0)/SUM(IF (repeat_m0>0,users,NULL)) as m0_repeat,
sum(repeat_m1)/SUM(IF (repeat_m1>0,users,NULL)) as m1_repeat,
sum(repeat_m2)/SUM(IF (repeat_m2>0,users,NULL)) as m2_repeat,
sum(repeat_m3)/SUM(IF (repeat_m3>0,users,NULL)) as m3_repeat,
sum(repeat_m4)/SUM(IF (repeat_m4>0,users,NULL)) as m4_repeat,
sum(repeat_m5)/SUM(IF (repeat_m5>0,users,NULL)) as m5_repeat,
sum(repeat_m6)/SUM(IF (repeat_m6>0,users,NULL)) as m6_repeat,
sum(repeat_m7)/SUM(IF (repeat_m7>0,users,NULL)) as m7_repeat,
sum(repeat_m8)/SUM(IF (repeat_m8>0,users,NULL)) as m8_repeat,
sum(repeat_m9)/SUM(IF (repeat_m9>0,users,NULL)) as m9_repeat,
sum(repeat_m10)/SUM(IF (repeat_m10>0,users,NULL)) as m10_repeat,
sum(repeat_m11)/SUM(IF (repeat_m11>0,users,NULL)) as m11_repeat,
sum(repeat_m12)/SUM(IF (repeat_m12>0,users,NULL)) as m12_repeat,
sum(repeat_m13)/SUM(IF (repeat_m13>0,users,NULL)) as m13_repeat,
sum(repeat_m14)/SUM(IF (repeat_m14>0,users,NULL)) as m14_repeat,
sum(repeat_m15)/SUM(IF (repeat_m15>0,users,NULL)) as m15_repeat,
sum(repeat_m16)/SUM(IF (repeat_m16>0,users,NULL)) as m16_repeat,
sum(repeat_m17)/SUM(IF (repeat_m17>0,users,NULL)) as m17_repeat,
sum(repeat_m18)/SUM(IF (repeat_m18>0,users,NULL)) as m18_repeat,
sum(repeat_m19)/SUM(IF (repeat_m19>0,users,NULL)) as m19_repeat,
sum(repeat_m20)/SUM(IF (repeat_m20>0,users,NULL)) as m20_repeat,
sum(repeat_m21)/SUM(IF (repeat_m21>0,users,NULL)) as m21_repeat,
sum(repeat_m22)/SUM(IF (repeat_m22>0,users,NULL)) as m22_repeat,
sum(repeat_m23)/SUM(IF (repeat_m23>0,users,NULL)) as m23_repeat,
sum(repeat_m24)/SUM(IF (repeat_m24>0,users,NULL)) as m24_repeat,
sum(repeat_m25)/SUM(IF (repeat_m25>0,users,NULL)) as m25_repeat,
sum(repeat_m26)/SUM(IF (repeat_m26>0,users,NULL)) as m26_repeat,
sum(repeat_m27)/SUM(IF (repeat_m27>0,users,NULL)) as m27_repeat,
sum(repeat_m28)/SUM(IF (repeat_m28>0,users,NULL)) as m28_repeat,
sum(repeat_m29)/SUM(IF (repeat_m29>0,users,NULL)) as m29_repeat,
sum(repeat_m30)/SUM(IF (repeat_m30>0,users,NULL)) as m30_repeat
from repeat_cohort_numbers
```

For details, check: https://medium.com/@devamsaxena/creating-customer-retention-cohorts-on-big-query-b521b0e4db1f

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

The following query shows the 30-day retention by month which answers the question, "For all users who sign up in a month, how many made a purchase 30 days after account signup?"

```
with user_signups as (
  select user_id, cast(account_signup as date) as account_signup_date from <signup_table>
),
most_recent_purchase as (
  select user_id, max(cast(timestamp as date)) as most_recent_purchase_date from <purchase_table> group by 1
),
joined as (
  select 
    user_id, 
    account_signup_date, 
    most_recent_purchase_date, 
    date_diff(most_recent_purchase_date,account_signup_date,DAY) as retained_days
  from user_signups
  inner join most_recent_purchase using(user_id)
),
prep as (
  select 
    format_date('%Y-%m', account_signup_date) as signupYYYYMM
    count(*) as users,
    sum(case when retained_days >= 30 then 1 else 0 end) as retained_users_30
  from joined
  group by 1
)
select
  signupYYYYMM,
  users,
  retained_users_30/users as retention_30_days
from prep
order by 1
```

Hopefully you can see how this could be modified to do weekly or yearly cohorts and different retention periods.

A few caveats... this query assumes all users who create an account made a purchase.  If there are account users who did not make purchases, you will want to left join and you might need to tweak your retention calculation/definition (depending on business purpose).